# One too many tags: maxtotalconnections?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Is there some point to having [maxtotalconnections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxtotalconnections) as a tag which I haven't seen?

There are five questions tagged thusly, and none of them benefit from that tag.

*Later...* OK, I've removed that tag from the questions and VTC a couple of them.

Comment: 5 questions in almost 6 years of existence... Let's just get it over with.

Comment: Yeah close vote the bad ones and then remove the tag, tomorrow it will be gone

Comment: You can post an answer with the actions you took... if fully transparent, might as well go all the way.

Answer (score 4):

I have removed the tag from the five questions which had it.

Some of them were also candidates for VTC, which I did.

I await the running of the cleanup script to remove the tag.

Comment: You ask a question, and then 20 minutes later decide to take unilateral action. Sorry, that's not how "burninate requests" are supposed to work. No one even had a chance to chime in with "no, this tag is important because x".

Comment: @CodyGray in his defence: He acted on the comments Petter and Tunaki gave. And judging by the amount of questions tagged with it, is there any actual expectation of someone jumping in and defending the tag?

Comment: Comments are not answers. They don't even *hope* to establish a consensus. You don't "act on" comments. Someone with 10k+ reputation should know that; it isn't Andrew's first time to Meta. If there was literally no expectation of value for the tag, then you wouldn't bother to ask on Meta in the first place. I don't see anything defensible here. @luk

Comment: @CodyGray I mostly agree with the second part "wouldn't bother to ask on Meta". But still I can understand Andrew: complex tag with a lot of questions -> wait for answers on meta, simple tag with a few questions -> wait for minimal feedback confirming what OP wanted to do in the first place, basic tag with 1 or 2 question -> silently act.

Comment: @luk2302 You are correct in both your comments: I was perhaps too easily swayed by the comments on my question, and I didn't want to unilaterally decide to delete all occurrences of the tag.